# How do I calculate the capacity factor of a company that uses trucks to do delivery in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, math

hope you are well.
I am trying to do an exercises where I have to calculate the capacity factor of the company that does deliveries around the word.

The total capacity factor must be expresses in %.
Data provided:

- Kerb weight of the vehicle is its nladen (empty) weight
  -GVM stands for gross vehicle weight. This is the maximum allowable laden weight for the vehicle. 
  -A single trip may last between 2 and 10 days. 
  -Departure_date
  -Return_date

Does anybody now How to figure out at least the operation to calculate the capacity factor?

Every help is appreciate it.

---

¦ Capacity ¦

### ¦    42%   ¦

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: A definition of `Capacity Factor` would also be useful. I for one dont automatically know exactly what that equasion is